# How does $1^\infty=\infty$?

Tags: limits, infinity

I remember hearing in school long ago that $1^\infty=\infty$.

I was just wondering if anyone could explain this in laymen's terms?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Glad to hear someone say that.  I have definitely been skeptical since the day my Pre-Calculus teacher said it.

Comment: Which school???

Comment: To the degree that one can make sense of the assertion, it is false.

Comment: For beginners dealing with symbol $\infty$, it is better to keep in mind that it is not a number which can be used in operations like $+, -, \times, /, \text{^}$.  Hence the statement $1^{\infty} = \infty$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1^\infty$ is [indeterminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), as this *Wikipedia* entry explains. Or perhaps you remember something like $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$ ?

Comment: Given OP says "$1^\infty=\infty$," probably more like $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok. I feel that common sense and deductive reasoning would conclude that 1 ^ (any number) = 1.  But infinity is not a 'number' but rather an abstract concept.  So Ii wonder if there is any situation where it even makes any sense to say 1 ^ (abstract concept)?  FYI, the teacher just made the statement as I presented it... she didn't provide any rationale and truthfully I've never really believed it because it sounds like nonsense to me... but I did assume that she said it because some real mathematician had provided some rationale.

Comment: @anon I can neither confirm nor deny your assertion... because I have no clue what either your or Lucian's equations mean :)

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$ : so much is indeed true... *But* this is *not* the *only* limit of this form... Imagine that instead of $1$ we would have a quantity which tends to $1$ from below : then the limit would be $0$ ; if it tends from above, the limit is $\infty$. So a limit does not properly exist *for all cases*, but each situation has to be assessed individually. For instance, Euler's famous constant $e$ can also be defined as a limit of the form $1^\infty$, yet its value is neither $0$, nor $1$, nor $\infty$, but about $2.72^-$.

Comment: @BrandonMoore $1^\infty$ is not a number, but is just a name for a specific indeterminate form.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "$1^\infty$". If you mean $\lim_{\,n\rightarrow\infty\!}1^n,$ then it can be taken to mean $1$. But generally it is not something that a mathematician would write. The most sensible thing to do is to regard arithmetic operations involving the symbol $\infty$ as meaningless. You can play around with such symbols in a very limited way, once you have understood some basic maths, but the symbol probably causes more confusion than enlightenment, and there is a good case for saying that we would be better off without it, except as an arbitrary name in the one-point compactification of the complex numbers (or, in the dual form $\pm\infty$, in the two-point compactification of the real numbers). If you don't understand this or the other comments or answers, it's not a problem: just treat "arithmetic with infinity" as meaningless, and you will be wiser than most of your colleagues.